# Getting [object HTMLLIElement] instead of text. Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a simple javascript function that chooses a random list item in an unordered list with the press of a button. It works fine, the console spits out a random list item when the button is clicked but when I try to display it on the HTML page all I am getting is this weird [object HTMLLIElement] instead of the text.

The goal is to display the text inbetween the list item. When I click the button it chooses a random list item for example: `<li>5</li>` but I would like for just the `5` to be displayed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
</ul>

<button id="randomize">randomize</button>

<p id="result">hello</p>
```

and the JS:

```
var randomize = document.getElementById("randomize");
var listItems = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

randomize.addEventListener("click", randomizeIt);

function randomizeIt () {
    var randomItem = listItems[Math.floor(Math.random() * listItems.length)];
    result.innerHTML = randomItem;
    console.log(randomItem);
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you set result to the `li` object, you have to get the text inside

```
result.innerHTML = randomItem.textContent;
```

Comment: Hadeaz just suggested to do randomItem.innerHTML this worked as well, could you explain the difference and which one is better to use?

Comment: In this case it does the same because it does not contain any html elements in it. If it was  `<li><sapn>7</span></li>` innerHTML would give you `<sapn>7</span>` while `textContent` would still give you `7`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the value you need to access the innerHTML of the `<li>`.

```
result.innerHTML = randomItem.innerHTML;
```